# How to connect USB midi keyboard to qsynth using qjackctl?

Tags: sound, alsa, jack, midi

I have following sound configuration for my PC-300 USB Midi keyboard on Ubuntu 17.04:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1228000 irq 282
 1 [HD             ]: USB-Audio - USB Sound Blaster HD
                      Creative Technology USB Sound Blaster HD at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, full speed
 2 [PC300          ]: USB-Audio - PC-300
                      Roland PC-300 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed
```

Next, I want to use JACK to configure the output from the MIDI keyboard. I start `qjackctl` and click "Setup" button and then the "Advanced" tab:

[image]

Now, after pressing "Ok" button here, I return to main window in `qjackctl` and I start the JACK daemon by clicking the "Start" button.

Then I open a new terminal window and launch `qsynth`, and click the "Setup" button and then click the "Soundfots" tab. Here I select the sound font to be:

```
/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2
```

Then I go to `qjackctl` and click the "Connect" button, and then click the "Audio" tab:

[image]

Then I click the "Midi" tab:

[image]

Note that no readable client are shown in the left pane. Hence, it is not possible to connect the Midi keyboard to Qsynth here.

Finally, I click the "ALSA" tab:

[image]

and as seen from the screenshot above: here also, it is not possible to connect the Midi keyboard to Qsynth.

How can I connect my USB midi keyboard to qsynth using JACK?

**Note**:

The JACK deamon setup is likely to be correct since I was able to connect the keyboard to fluidsynth using `jackd`.

Comment: see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit#MIDI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Ardour's configuration [page](http://manual.ardour.org/setting-up-your-system/setting-up-midi/midi-on-linux/)

> The right approach for using MIDI on Linux when using JACK 2 is to use
>   `a2jmidid` as a bridge between ALSA MIDI and JACK.

So after starting `qjackctl` I had to run `a2jmidid -e`, and after that I could start QSynth, and finally go back to `qjackctl` and connect the MIDI keyboard with a QSynth engine.

Comment: hey, I am doing as you say but after running a2jmidid - e starting qsynth won't appear on qjackctl graph.... please help.